# Can I create dynamic pivot query from key value table with different data types?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, key-value, dynamic-sql

I have a key-value pairs table. I have created a script using dynamic sql that pivots the table correctly. However, the keys have different data types. Is there a way to cast the keys during or after the pivot dynamically? I can have the data types in the same key-value pairs table for each key or in a separate table linkable by the key.

Dynamic sql is used because I wont always know the columns. There will always be a data type.

An example of the starting table:

```
sampleid     key   value    datatype
------------------------------------
1001        Name   Andrew    varchar(50)
1001        Date   20150129  datetime
1002        Name   Anna      varchar(50)
1002        Date   20150129  datetime
```

Final result would be this with name as nvarchar and date as datetime:
The script is a stored procedure that creates this into a view. The view is being accessed via external applications like SAS and Olive which pick up the datatype from the view. Of course this isn't ideal but it is what I have been tasked with attempting!

```
sampleid  name      date
-----------------------------
1001     Andrew    20150129
1002     Anna      20150129
```

Comment: `Anna` isn't a datetime so you won't be able to convert that. What do you want for the final result? You can pivot this without converting the data, why do you need to convert it?

Comment: Thanks for the catch @bluefeet! I have corrected and added some more info.

Comment: If you need to be able to create this on the fly - dynamically, then you won't be able to do this in a view.  Dynamic SQL can only be run in a stored procedure.

Comment: Right. That is acceptable. We have a task that runs the stored procedure as needed. Is it possible to cast the data types dynamically? @bluefeet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using dynamic SQL, you'll just have to crate two separate lists of "new columns" as a string. One list will include the column names being converted to your datatype, the second will be used for the PIVOT function.

The code would be:

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsConversion AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- get the list of [key] items for the columns used in the PIVOT
select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME([key])
            from yourtable
            group by [key], datatype           
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- get the list of columns for the final select
-- include a conversion of the columns into the correct datatype
select @colsConversion 
  = STUFF((SELECT ', cast(' + QUOTENAME([key]) +' as '+ datatype+') as ' + QUOTENAME([key])
            from yourtable
            group by [key], datatype           
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- the converted columns go in the final select list 
-- while the other @cols are used inside the PIVOT
set @query = 'SELECT sampleid, ' + @colsConversion + ' 
            from 
            (
              select sampleid, [key], value
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               max(value)
               for [key] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p; '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc812/5)