# SQL. PIVOT returning NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, null, pivot

I've simple trying to convert rows to columns, but PIVOT returning NULL values. Before I've tried simple `PIVOT`, but unsuccessfully. For now I'm trying `Dynamic PIVOT`, but still the same result - `NULL` values.

Before pivot (how It is for now):

```
  1 test   -- Column alias name
----------
|  One   | -- Values which should be pivoted.
|  Two   | -- Values which should be pivoted.
|  Three | -- Values which should be pivoted.
|  Four  | -- Values which should be pivoted.
|  Five  | -- Values which should be pivoted.
```

After pivot (how It should be):

```
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test5 | -- New columns alias names.
---------------------------------------------
|  One  |  Two  | Three | Four  | Five  | -- Pivoted values.
```

Here is my code:

```
  DECLARE   @sql    AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

  -- Below selecting new column names
    SELECT @cols += '[' + Name1 + '],' + 
                    '[' + Name2 + '],' + 
                    '[' + Name3 + '],' + 
                    '[' + Name4 + '],' + 
                    '[' + Name5 + '],' 
    FROM   (SELECT  'Test1' AS Name1, 
                    'Test2' AS Name2, 
                    'Test3' AS Name3, 
                    'Test4' AS Name4, 
                    'Test5' AS Name5                        
            ) a 

    SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
    SET @sql    = N'SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
    -- If I selecting only this subquery (select clause) It returning values in 1 column (as shown in 'Before Pivot'), which should be pivoted to row (as shown in 'After Pivot')
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5   NA.ItemNo           AS  [1 test]                                                
        FROM        FormI                           AS  FI
        INNER JOIN  FormF                           AS  FF
        ON          FF.FormVId  = FI.FormVId
        INNER JOIN  FormV                           AS  FormV
        ON          FI.FormVId  = FormV.Id
        INNER JOIN  NavArt                          AS  NA
        ON          FI.ArticleId    = NA.Id
        WHERE       FI.WorkShiftId  = 10
    ) x 
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN ([1 test])
        FOR [1 test] IN (' + @cols + ') 
    ) p'
    EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

For now this code returning only column names, but with `NULL` values. Like that:

```
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test5 | -- New columns alias names.
---------------------------------------------
|  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | -- NULL instead of values
```

Have you ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to change this

`SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
        FROM 
        (...`

To this:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT ''TestValue'' AS Test1, * 
            FROM 
            (...
```

In this case It returning 1 more column `Test1`, but with value `TestValue`

```
|  Test1  | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | Test4 | Test5 | -- 2x Test1 columns.
---------------------------------------------
|TestValue|  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL |  NULL | -- TestValue added
```

But I did this only for testing purpose, this is not good method for me, that because values are dynamic.

**EDIT 2**
For now my @cols looks like:

```
SELECT @cols += '[' + Name + '],' 
            FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5   NA.ItemNo AS Name--, 
                            FROM        FormI                       AS  FI
                            INNER JOIN  FormF                       AS  FF
                            ON          FF.FormVId  = FI.FormVId
                            INNER JOIN  FormV                       AS  FormV
                            ON          FI.FormVId  = FormV.Id
                            INNER JOIN  NavArticles                 AS  NA
                            ON          FI.ArticleId        = NA.Id
                            WHERE       FI.WorkShiftId      = 10

                    ) a
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to provided some sample data for your tables, possibly the table structures, even a sql fiddle - which would help in determining why you are getting `null`.

Comment: This select clause: `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 Na.ItemNo AS [1 test]....` returning 1 column with 5 rows `nvarchar` format, for reality these 5 values are something like: `QTP 953 STP` It have white spaces, maybe that Is problem? This should be really simple when I have only 1 column which I want to pivot, but I can't understand where is problem...

Comment: Again, I'd suggest posting some sample data, the table structure.  But `Test1` as a column has to match exactly what you have being returned by your subquery. What the exact data in `[1 test]`? Does that match what you've listed as the values in the `PIVOT` `IN` clause?  If not, then that's your issue. But without seeing actual data then we'd be guessing.

Comment: If I correctly understood your idea, `@cols=` should have the same values as in the `[1 test]`? But in this case Column names the same as values. Column names should be different.

Comment: When you are pivoting data the "new column names" have to appear in the result set, what does your data look like? Does it match exactly what you are using as the final column names?  Again **without seeing** data, we are guessing. Show us some data. You aren't providing enough details to solve the full problem. Create a sql fiddle with some sample data, your tables, etc.

Comment: For now I changed `@cols` like this: `SELECT @cols += '[' + Name + '],' 
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 NA.ItemNo AS Name
        FROM  FormI....` the same query which I used to get data in `[1 test]`. Maybe I misunderstand something, but can I chage names of pivoted columns? For now values and column names are equal.

Comment: If you want the final column names to be different, then you'll have to create a separate column list where you get the actual column name and then alias it. [Here is an example of 2 column lists, due to conversion being needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487165/426671)

Comment: I really can't understand how It working, It's only difference between `@cols` and `@colsConversion` is that I need use `CAST`? Could you provide example how `@colsConversion` should look like in my code, please? I updated my question with with code how `@cols` looks like for now (look at `EDIT 2`)

Comment: I've tried to use like this: `SELECT @colsConversion += '[''CAST(' + Name+ ' AS ' + NVARCHAR(MAX) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME([Name]) +'],'`, but I got following errors: `'NVARCHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name.` and `Incorrect syntax near 'a'.`

Comment: I'm not going to keep guessing at your problem, if you edit your question to include some sample data, table structures and the final desired result, then I'll continue to help.

Comment: I can't to It, It's confidential. This worked for me: `SELECT @colsConversion += 'CAST([' + Name+ '] AS ' + 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME('NewColumnName')+ ','` Thank you! But, for now all pivoted columns have the same name `NewColumnName`, Is It possible to make something like: `NewColumnName1`, `NewColumnName2` etc.?

Comment: Yes, you could make the data anonymous to give some sort of sample of what you are working with. There are ways to do it.

Comment: Could you help one more time with making names different, please? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The values used in the `IN` clause in the pivot must match the column values you are pivoting. If you want to rename the columns you can do it in the select statement. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    [One Test]   as [NameOne], 
    [Two Test]   as [NameTwo], 
    [Three Test] as [NameThree], 
    [Four Test]  as [NameFour]
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 NA.ItemId AS  [1 test]
FROM        .....               AS  FI
    INNER JOIN  .....           AS  FF
    ON          FF..= FI..
    INNER JOIN  ....            AS  FormV
    ON          FI..= FormV..
    INNER JOIN  ....            AS  NA
    ON          FI..= NA.Id
    WHERE       FI..= 10
) a
PIVOT
(
MIN([1 test])
FOR [1 test] IN ([One Test], [Two Test], [Three Test], [Four Test])
) AS piv;
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But `[One Test], [Two Test], [ Three Test], [Four Test]` values are returned from subquery, how can I use them in first select clause? This `SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 NA.ItemId AS  [1 test]` returning me these 4 values:  `[One Test], [Two Test], [ Three Test], [Four Test]`.

Comment: I wrote only simple version of my big code, It Is used in stored procedure where are used parameters, so these values:  `[One Test], [Two Test], [ Three Test], [Four Test]` are dynamic, depends on parameter input. So I don't know If I can use these values in case as you shown me.

Comment: @Infinity No, if it's dynamic this won't work, then you probably have to build the entire pivot statement using dynamic code.

Comment: @Infinity What is `SomeText` supposed to be in the example? It's used as a literal value for the column right now. It's a bit hard to understand the code and issue without seeing the actual code.

Comment: I don't need `SomeText` at all, I just tried It, that because It was shown in example tutorial which I followed.